# Sync migrations with actual changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

EF Migrations could not automatically detect some complex changes, so I created an empty migration and made changes by hand to `Up()` and `Down()`. 
I updated the database, and everything worked in both forward and reverse directions.

But later, when I made more changes and created a new migration, *it automatically added all kinds of changes which were not needed - as I already handled them manually in the previous migration*.

I know I can delete all migrations and start from scratch, but that'll create far too many problems, so I don't want to do that.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the offending junk from the `Up()` and `Down()` functions
Compile
`Update-Database`

Answer (score 1):

You can always establish a new baseline if you don't have prior released databases out there. Delete all the old migrations then run:

```
Add-Migration MyBaseline –IgnoreChanges
Update-Database
```

Now your model and database will be in sync and you can make model changes and create new migrations. I usually turn automigrations on until I am ready to deploy then I roll them into a single migration that I can script out to clients.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#step3

Comment: Yes I know of this option, but like I said above it creates problems for me I want to avoid - but if that weren't the case then I'd use this approach as it's simple and neat. The answer I posted works for me.

Comment: Yes, running empty Up() Down() has the same net effect.